# How to move a directory in IntelliJ/Phpstorm into its own project?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have a PhpStorm project that has two applications in it, and type hinting always shows a warning saying there are two instances of a class.

I want to separate the applications into their own projects without losing the existing umbrella-project's settings. I don't want to recreate all the settings from scratch.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Copy `.idea` subfolder and edit few things there (e.g. rename `.iml` file; change reference to that file in `modules.xml`, some possible edits in `workspace.xml`). Might be other places as well ... as your current project may include different paths etc ( I never had to do such separation myself -- only cloning projects; and without knowing your project layout (what gets extracted, how it all organized etc) cannot give any better advices.

Comment: Another approach: make new separate project first and then copy some stuff from old one while project is closed (again -- all project configs are stored in `.idea` subfolder).